# Collect a return value from a javascript function using BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to collect Agencies phone number using BeautifulSoup from this url: https://www.cv-library.co.uk/companies/agencies/0-9.

But the problem is, I have to click a link first which is bound to a javascript function called **"contactDetails()"** to show a number. I managed to click all the links using Selenium. but how can I now collect the numbers?

So, what should I do now to overcome the issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Note: I am new in web-scraping.

```
import requests,bs4
from selenium import webdriver

site_url = "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/companies/agencies/0-9"

#---------------------------------- Opening Firefox with Selenium Webdrivre ---------------
#browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
#I need my Firefox browser's current profile for a reason.
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\i27jf7iw.default")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
browser.get(site_url)

#---------------------------------- Clicking Phone Buttons ---------------------
phone_btn = browser.find_elements_by_link_text("Phone - Click to View")
for i in range(0,20):
    phone_btn[i].click()
```

Comment: every link `"Phone - click to View"` has number in attribute `onclick` (ie. `contactDetails( this, 154513 )`) which JavaScript use to read phone number from server - ie. `https://www.cv-library.co.uk/account-contact-details?id=154513`. You could try to read it and you will no need Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It clicks all buttons, and later it get numbers.

But after few test I got "Contact details view limit reached" :) So there is limit for clicks.

```
from selenium import webdriver

site_url = "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/companies/agencies/0-9"

# --- Opening Firefox with Selenium Webdrivre ---

browser = webdriver.Firefox() 

#I need my Firefox browser's current profile for a reason.
#profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\i27jf7iw.default")
#browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

browser.get(site_url)

# --- Clicking Phone Buttons ---

phone_btn = browser.find_elements_by_link_text("Phone - Click to View")
for btn in phone_btn:
    btn.click()

numbers = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('company-profile-phone')
for num in numbers:
    print('number:', num.text)
```

---

Version without `Selenium`

Every link `"Phone - click to View"` has number in attribute `onclick` (ie. `contactDetails( this, 154513 )`) which JavaScript uses to get number from server using always the same url with this number - ie. `https://www.cv-library.co.uk/account-contact-details?id=1545‌​13`.

It works for awhile - probably I reached the click's limit :)

```
import requests
import bs4

site_url = "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/companies/agencies/0-9"
phone_url = "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/account-contact-details?id="

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({
    #"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", 
#    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    #"Accept-Language": "pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
})
print(session.headers)

r = session.get(site_url)
print(r.status_code)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

#print(r.text)
all_p = soup.find_all('p', class_='company-profile-phone')

for p in all_p:
    number = p.a['onclick'][22:-2]
    print('Phone ID:', number)

    session.headers.update({
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    })

    r = session.get(phone_url + number)

    if r.status_code != 200:
        print("Contact details view limit reached")
    else:
        data = r.json()

        if "email" in data:
            print('email:', data['email'])
        if "phone" in data:
            print('phone:', data['telephone'])
    print('---')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked. And yes, it has a limit. That is why I wanted to use my Firefox current profile to switch different IP addresses.

Comment: By the way, your without selenium version is raising a ValueError.

Comment: I run it and don't have ValueError. What exactly it shows after text "ValueError", I display phone and email and maybe some companies has no email (or phone) - you may check `if "email" in datta:` or ` `if "phone" in data:`

Comment: I add `if "phone" in data:` to code. I check also if you reach view limit.

Comment: yes! Now it is working...Actually as I mentioned earlier I am new to web scraping, I don't understand your without selenium version code fully.So, I started learning your code line by line. :-)

Comment: Will you please tell how you find this URL: https://www.cv-library.co.uk/account-contact-details?id=1545‌​13

Comment: In Chrome/Firefox I open your page, next I open DevTools (shortkey F12) and I go to tab `Network` and I click XHR - it will show only JavaScript/AJAX requests. When I click  `"Phone - Click to View"` then I see new requests in `Network`. I can click it and see its url, headers, response (as text or JSON dictionary).